# Creating Horizontal Scroll Bar Using Json?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-play

I am trying to create the CardView ScrollBar UI like Google Play.

I was following [this](http://khmertechtrain.tk/index.php/2017/10/03/create-a-vertical-scroll-and-horizontal-scroll-app-like-google-play-store/) tutorial but stuck at the models classes and can't move further.

My Json is like this:

```
{
  "Cards": {
    "Recently Updated": [
      {
        "Name": "A",
        "img": "a.png",
        "link": "alink.com"
      },
      {
        "Name": "B",
        "img": "b.png",
        "link": "blink.com"
      },
      {
        "Name": "C",
        "img": "c.png",
        "link": "clink.com"
      }
    ],
    "Newly Arrives": [
      {
        "Name": "A",
        "img": "a.png",
        "link": "alink.com"
      },
      {
        "Name": "L",
        "img": "L.png",
        "link": "Llink.com"
      },
      {
        "Name": "z",
        "img": "z.png",
        "link": "zlink.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help to create the same.

I want to achive like this :
[image]

How can i add cardview scrollbar like above image

Comment: Upload your model class so we can see what happened. Building this page is a big work

Comment: @SoonSantos I've add the JSON data in the main question. and i have'nt created any model classes cause the tutorial i was following using offline scheme but i will not. please help me with this.

Comment: Would you paste the codes you stuck? No need for picture.

Comment: The models I didn't get them sir. I started following the tutorial, the link in main quest, the creation of base models are not clear and I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a model you need to follow the tree the JSON is showing you.
Look at the picture from the outside rectangles to the inside rectangles.

[image: Json divided in blocks]

First of all, you have all the JSON content as a block.

This is going to be my first model class

**MainCard.java**

```
public class MainCard {

    @SerializedName("Cards")
    public Cards cards;

}
```

Notice that my MainCard (my first and biggest rectangle) contains inside the Cards rectangle. That is why it has the public variable Cards.

Second, let's move to the second rectangle. (Cards)

**Cards.java**

```
public class Cards {

    @SerializedName("Recently Updated")
    public List<Item> recentlyUpdates;
    @SerializedName("Newly Arrives")
    public List<Item> newlyArrives;

}
```

The Cards rectangle has two rectangles inside it, Recently Updated and Newly Arrives, that is why I created this two variables.

Finally, notice that the rectangle inside Recently Updated and the rectangles inside Newly Arrives is a List of something (which I called Item - [name, img, link]). That's why I created the recentlyUpdated variable as a List.

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("Name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("img")
    public String img_url;
    public String link;

}
```

**NOTES**

@SerializedName should contain the exact same name your JSON provides, for example, in Cards.java, my variable name is recentlyUpdates and my @SerializedName("") is Recently Updated (which is the exact same name we have in the JSON response). However, if your variable name is the same as your JSON, you do not need to put @SerializedName, this happens in Item.java in the link variable.

**Retrofit**

If you JSON is on an online server, you should use some library to call this content. I would recommend you to use [retrofit 2 by square](https://github.com/square/retrofit).

Add the dependencies to your build.gradle (Module:app) file under the dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // Retrofit 2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

Then you should create a service that will call your JSON object.

**CardsService.java** (Note: this is an interface)

```
public interface CardsService {

    String BASE_URL = "http://yourbaseurl.api/";

    @GET("endpoint")
    Call<MainCard> getCards();

}
```

And in your MainActivity you call the service to get the JSON data.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(CardsService.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        CardsService service = retrofit.create(CardsService.class);

        Call<MainCard> call = service.getCards();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MainCard>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainCard> call, Response<MainCard> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Got a successful response (Code 200...300)

                    MainCard mainCard = response.body();

                    if (mainCard != null && mainCard.cards != null) {
                        List<Item> recentlyUpdates = mainCard.cards.recentlyUpdates;
                        List<Item> newlyArrives = mainCard.cards.newlyArrives;

                        // Use your information to set up the recyclerview as the tutorial you
                        // showed describe.
                        setupRecyclerView(recentlyUpdates, newlyArrives);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Got a unsucessful response (Code 401, 405, 409...)
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainCard> call, Throwable t) {
                // Failed to connect to the server
                // Possible causes: No internet connection, Server is broken.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you are not family with retrofit you should read some tutorials on medium, as [this one](https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-your-hand-dirty-with-retrofit-2-a-type-safe-http-client-for-android-and-java-c546f88b3a51), and you can also check [this project](https://github.com/soonsam123/Retrofit2Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soon/karat/retrofitfs/fragments/UserReposFragment.java) to learn more about the topic.

**EDIT**

**HOW TO SETUP THE ITEMS IN A RECYCLER VIEW?**

After you get a successful response you can call the `setupRecyclerView(List<Item> items)` method to display your items in a recycler view. I'll do it using only the recentlyUpdates list, then you customize in the way you want to display both.

```
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Got a successful response (Code 200...300)

                    MainCard mainCard = response.body();

                    if (mainCard != null && mainCard.cards != null) {
                        List<Item> recentlyUpdates = mainCard.cards.recentlyUpdates;
                        List<Item> newlyArrives = mainCard.cards.newlyArrives;

                        // ***** Use your information to set up the recyclerview. ***** 
                        // I am going to set up only the recentlyUpdates list.
                        setupRecyclerView(recentlyUpdates);
                    }
                }
```

Create a RecyclerView in your xml file

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

Back in your activity, cast the recycler view, add the layout manager and the adapter.

```
private void setupRecyclerView(List<Item> itemsList) {

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyCardsAdapter(itemsList, this));
    }
```

**MyCardsAdapter.java**

```
public class MyCardsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCardsAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<Item> itemsList;
    private Context context;

    public MyReposAdapter(List<Item> itemsList, Context context) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);

        return new ItemHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get each item.
        Item singleItem = itemsList.get(position);

        // singleItem is each Item.java you created. And holder contains the widgets you created in single_item.xml to display the items information.
        holder.textViewName.setText(singleItem.name);
        holder.textViewImage.setText(sigleItem.image_url);
        holder.textViewLink.setText(singleItem.link);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }


    public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewImage;
        public TextView textViewLink;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
            textViewImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_image);
            textViewLink = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_link);

        }

    }

}
```

**single_item.xml**

This is the layout of each item that will be displyed in the recyclerview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <!-- 1. Name -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <!-- 2. Image URL -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="URL"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_name"/>

            <!-- 3. Link -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_link"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Language"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_url"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much sir for that deep Answer, honestly i didn't expect that good answer. But i got a problem sir in the CardsService.java the @GET("bga8c") is showing an error which is `@GET not applicable to the filed` why that so ?

Comment: Do u have the base_url and endpoint of the api you are calling? like this [example](http://api.tvmaze.com/shows)

Comment: You need to set the correct link, for example, in this link api `http://api.tvmaze.com/shows` the BASE_URL is `String BASE_URL = http://api.tvmaze.com/` and the endpoint is `@GET("shows")`. You also need to make sure that this api you are calling needs a @GET method. @GET is used when you are getting information, for example getting a list of cards. @POST is used to post new information like registering a new user and @PUT is used to change some information like editing a user photo.

Comment: Edit your answer and upload your whole CardsService.java, please.

Comment: `package google.example;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface CardsService {
    String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/";

    @GET("/bga8c/")
    Call<MainCard> getCards;
}`

Comment: It is missing the parentheses right here `Call<MainCard> getCards();`

Comment: Holy Shame, was searching for the mistake in the whole project. I am really glad that you helped me. Just if you got time can you help me to create the vertical ui ? the tutorial just not working for me.

Comment: You can follow [this file](https://github.com/soonsam123/Retrofit2Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soon/karat/retrofitfs/fragments/UserReposFragment.java) in my project, I do the same exact thing you are doing. I call retrofit and setup the result in a recyclerview. This is a bit long, I suggest you to watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqty1cT69yk) and learn first how to display the result in a vertical recyclerview. After you master this, you go to the google play screen. If my answer was helpful, please accept it. I'll upload some code latter when I have time.

Comment: I added the code in my current answer. I did not debug it, if something goes wrong please let me know

Comment: @SoonSantos Implemented the recyclerview in just a minute. It worked like a charm ! Now just trying to know how to create that Horizontal slider in card view like I asked in the main question.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!