# How to access json array (Android)

Tags: android, json, weather, openweathermap

I'm creating a weather app using the openweathermap api, and need to access the elements of a json array called "list". It contains the weather forecast for the next several days. I'm using retrofit to parse all the json data as well. Problem is that I cannot access the array at all. I can access the elements of city, however.

[json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2lUb.png)

[main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlllO.png)

[forecast output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQWCp.png)

[forecast list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo3EI.png)

[forecast item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2D1t.png)

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org")
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);

    final WeatherForecast forecast = retrofit.create(WeatherForecast.class);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Call<ForecastOutputData> callForecastRequest = forecast.getWeatherInfo(Double.toString(lat), Double.toString(lon), "imperial", "5", "key");

            callForecastRequest.enqueue(new Callback<ForecastOutputData>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ForecastOutputData> forecastCall, Response<ForecastOutputData> forecastResponse) {
                    ForecastOutputData forecastData = forecastResponse.body();
                    Log.d("GHEY",forecastData.getCity().getName());
                    Test.setText("Test " + forecastData.getList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ForecastOutputData> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("mytag", "mymessage",t);
                    Test.setText("Test FAIL");
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ForecastOutputData {
    private int cnt;
    private String cod;
    private double message;
    private List<ForecastList> forecastData;
    private City city;

    public String getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(String cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public int getCnt() {
        return cnt;
    }

    public void setCnt(int cnt) {
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }

    public List<ForecastList> getForecastData() {
        return forecastData;
    }

    public void setForecastData(List<ForecastList> forecastData) {
        this.forecastData = forecastData;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public double getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(double message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

import java.util.List;

class ForecastList {
    private int dt;
    private Main main;
    private List<Weather> weather;
    private Clouds clouds;
    private Wind wind;
    private Sys sys;
    private String dtTxt;

    public int getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(int dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Clouds getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public Wind getWind() {
        return wind;
    }

    public void setWind(Wind wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    public Sys getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    public void setSys(Sys sys) {
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    public String getDtTxt() {
        return dtTxt;
    }

    public void setDtTxt(String dtTxt) {
        this.dtTxt = dtTxt;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public class ForecastItem {
    private String cod;
    private double message;
    private int cnt;
    private List<ForecastList> list;
    private City city;

    public String getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(String cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public double getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(double message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCnt() {
        return cnt;
    }

    public void setCnt(int cnt) {
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }

    public List<ForecastList> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<ForecastList> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use pictures of code

Comment: try to convert your code from screenshots to text format.

Comment: Can u try to add serialized names in your pojo class

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456131/8383332) can help you.

Comment: I dont see forecastList property in the json structure

Comment: I just named it to ForecastList because the "List" is a reserved word, so I can't name my List as "List"

Comment: Put @JsonProperty("list") annotatin

Comment: To list property

Comment: where should i put that annotation?

Comment: @JsonProperty("list")
private List<ForecastList> forecastData;

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class ForecastResponse {
    private String cod;
    private String message;
    private City city;
    @JsonProperty("list")
    private List<ForecastItem> list;
}

public class ForecastItem {
  private int dt;
  //dt, main, weather, clouds etc

}
```

Comment: 1 class for root object, 1 class for forecast item. Why do you have 3 classes forecast output data, forecast list, forecast item?

Comment: Once I add that, that line gets the red underline and says "ForecastData.List does not have type parameters"

Comment: it's Java.util.List

Comment: ForecastOutputData refers to the main elements in the set, being "cod","message","cnt","list", and "city". ForecastList refers to the elements that are part of the json array called list, which includes "dt", "main", "weather", "clouds", etc.